# Why do xxxHOLiC and Tsubasa RESERVoir CHRoNiCLE use mixed casing?

Tags: tsubasa-chronicle, xxxholic

As you can see in the title and from the [xxxHOLiC](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=6052) and [Tsubasa RESERVoir CHRoNiCLE](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=4591) Anime News Network Pages pages, the titles for these 2 use mixed casing, on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsubasa%3a_Reservoir_Chronicle) page they have the japanese name as

> ツバサ-RESERVoir CHRoNiCLE- Tsubasa: Rezaboa Kuronikuru

I am wondering if there is a reason why the names come out like this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is going to boil down to "Japanese people think that mixed-case English words look cool".